# Why this .location works?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know why this js code works with this HTML:

```js
function getCityChoice() {
  const location = document.querySelector("form").location.value;
  console.log(location)
}
```

```html
<form name="reserve" action="index.html" method="get" onsubmit="return validate(event);">
  <div class="formData">
    <label for="first">Prénom</label><br>
    <input class="text-control" type="text" id="first" name="first" minlength="2" /><br>
  </div>
  <div class="formData">
    <label for="last">Nom</label><br>
    <input class="text-control" type="text" id="last" name="last" /><br>
  </div>
  <div class="formData">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label><br>
    <input class="text-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" /><br>
  </div>
  <div class="formData">
    <label for="birthdate">Date de naissance</label><br>
    <input class="text-control" type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" /><br>
  </div>
  <div class="formData">
    <label for="quantity">À combien de tournois GameOn avez-vous déjà participé ?</label><br>
    <input type="number" class="text-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="99">
  </div>
  <p class="text-label">A quel tournoi souhaitez-vous participer cette année ?</p>
  <div class="formData">
    <input class="checkbox-input" type="radio" id="location1" name="location" value="New York" />
    <label class="checkbox-label" for="location1">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  New York</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location2"
                  name="location"
                  value="San Francisco"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location2">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  San Francisco</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location3"
                  name="location"
                  value="Seattle"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location3">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Seattle</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location4"
                  name="location"
                  value="Chicago"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location4">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Chicago</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location5"
                  name="location"
                  value="Boston"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location5">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Boston</label
                >
                <input
                  class="checkbox-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id="location6"
                  name="location"
                  value="Portland"
                />
                <label class="checkbox-label" for="location6">
                  <span class="checkbox-icon"></span>
                  Portland</label
                >
              </div>
```

I know that I can use the shortcut for regular HTML attributes like .id but here .location is not an attribute but the value of name attribute.

I tried with an other project by using the value of the name attribute but in this case it doesn't work at all.

Can you explain why in this case it works, and why he can track the change of the value when a user change the choice of the city?

Comment: `location` is a reserved word; there already exists a `location` value on `window` before you define it. If you use a different name, it will stop working the same.

Comment: Where do you even call `getCityChoice`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey `const location` inside a `function` has nothing to do with `window.location`

Comment: @j08691 On a function who validate each field of a form

Comment: You are correct @JaromandaX, my apologies. The pattern recognizer recognized the wrong pattern ;).

Answer (score 2):

Because that is a form element. You can access the form's elements via their `name` attribute.

From [Mozilla Developer Network -> HTMLFormElement -> Accessing the form's elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#accessing_the_forms_elements):

> You can also get the form's element by using its `name` attribute as a key of the form, but using `elements` is a better approach—it contains only the form's elements, and it cannot be mixed with other attributes of the `form`.

You have an input with the name `location`.

```js
const checkboxValue = document.querySelector("form").location.value;
```

You can get that input's value using the line above.

Comment: Okey, but it seems work like an eventListener, no ? Because after an user change the choice of the location, the choice it's updated without using eventListner on the list of the checkboxes

Comment: More specifically, there are many elements with the name "location", all of which are `input`s with `type="radio"` which have different values. So getting the value of the radio button element with a given name will only return the one checked element that has that value. This is unique to radio buttons, I believe.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't know, I tried with an other exemple but this time the changement of the value is not tracked

Comment: @StevenSpysschaert I can't see the other example so I couldn't tell you. It may have to do with when you are getting the value; if you get the value outside of an event handler, it will always be the value it was at the time you got it, not at the time the event occurred.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You have right ! Thanks a lot. With your help now I have the ability to choose if an eventListener is required or not !